# Wasn't there a version of Ubuntu without any branding and with only free software? What was it called?

Tags: open-source

(This question is out of interest and not because I have a problem with my machine. If it belongs to some other forum, tell me instead of downvoting me.)

I remember that a couple of years ago, there used to be a fork of ubuntu that included only free software. (Free as Richard Stallman would like.)

It did not have firefox, had iceweasle. It did not have proprietary stuff in the kernel or anything. I had installed it just when Richard Stallman had visited my college. Did not like it at all as I could not use it for my laptop.

Does anyone know about/remember that OS? I just want the name.

Comment: Well, "Debian" ?  :-)

Comment: gnewsense it was. Such an old question. How did you get here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was [GNewSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNewSense) (see [here](http://www.gnewsense.org/) for the project's page).

There was an official [free version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobuntu) [**Gobuntu**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Gobuntu) too.

Comment: right. I totally forgot

Comment: Why did they kill those projects? I thought it made sense to do something like that just for the sake of freeedom. The same idea that has lead to todays awesome opensource+free software world. Thanks for the answer man

Comment: I think, because you can also use only free software and drivers in Ubuntu.